# zero-height rectangle contain point

Tags: actionscript-3

If I got a rectangle(0, 0, 100, 0) and a point (50, 0);

but when I test rectangle.containPoint, it always said false.

is that means a zero-height rectangle will not contain any point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can answer this question yourself: When something has no height - can you still see it?

Comment: No, it isn't. A zero-height rectangle may appear like a line, but only if you have set a lineStyle.  When you use boxes for anything in ActionScript - other than drawing with lineStyles, that is - the only measurements that matter are the height and width of the fill. This is true for masks, collision detection, etc. - why should it be any different here?

Comment: @weltraumpirat — In a geometrical sense, the zero height rectangle is a set of points, having the same `y` value, but different `x` values (ranging from the `x` of rectangle to `x` + `rectangle.width`. So he made bad assumptions of the language and its workings.

Comment: @joncys: We could really argue about that, because even your definition would imply that the rectangle has to have a height of exactly one point, but it becomes very obvious when you think about these points not as geometrical points, but as pixels:  If the rectangle has a height of no pixels, there can never be any pixels within it.

Comment: @weltraumpirat — there's nothing to argue about. Check your geometry. The rectangle is perfectly fine with having no height and containing points in it. That rectangle is called a line. Points are 1 dimensional and they can be on lines. This flipped him off, I guess. I have no quarrel to argue geometry here, sorry. I won't post another comment. Cheers everyone, glad the question was answered.

Comment: @joncys: I don't argue with your definition of a rectangle.  The key word to me is *contains*.  It implies that there has to be an area a point can be *within*, and where there's just a line, there is no area.